# Why is this jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Simple `hasclass` and `this.addclass` is not working

```
if ($('.sidebar-menu-container li').hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
}
```

[Link to codepen.](https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/ZyzPXO)

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please show all relevant code in the question. See [mcve]. Questions should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review the basics of your issue. Also take some time to read [ask]

Comment: you can use one line `$('.sidebar-menu-container li.current-menu-item').addClass('expanded')`

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('ul.sidebar-menu-container li.current-menu-item').addClass('expanded')
```

```css
.expanded {
  background:red !important;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
li {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu-container">
<li class="current-menu-item">asdasdasdasd</li>
<li>asdasdasdasd</li>
</ul>
```

1. Note that the parent of `LI` is `UL`
2. No need for iteration

Answer (score 2):

you have used `$(this)` inside `document.ready` so the `$(this)` refers to the document not the  `($('.sidebar-menu-container li')`.Using `this` outside any function refers to the global object

for your code to work

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

$('.sidebar-menu-container li').each(function(){
 if ($(this).hasClass('current-menu-item')) {

    $(this).addClass('expanded');
  }
})
 
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  background:red !important;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
li {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-menu-container">
<li class="current-menu-item">asdasdasdasd</li>
<li>asdasdasdasd</li>
</div>
```

or simply

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.sidebar-menu-container li.current-menu-item').addClass('expanded')
 
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  background:red !important;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
li {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-menu-container">
<li class="current-menu-item">asdasdasdasd</li>
<li>asdasdasdasd</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector `$('.sidebar-menu-container li')` is returning multiple elements, so if one of those elements has the class `current-menu-item` it will be `true`. You have to use a loop for that, or better yet:

```
$('.sidebar-menu-container li.current-menu-item').addClass('expanded');
```

The above code will select all `li` with `.current-menu-item` class and add `expanded` class for them. No loop or condition needed, jQuery does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your element return multiple element that's way its not working try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("li").click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
  }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be ok to use:

```
$('.sidebar-menu-container li.current-menu-item').addClass('expanded');
```

You don't need the if.

Comment: Oh yeah, like Guradio's suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.sidebar-menu-container li.current-menu-item').addClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  background:red !important;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
li {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-menu-container">
<li class="current-menu-item">asdasdasdasd</li>
<li>asdasdasdasd</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `if()` makes little sense.

Comment: Why not? He wants check specific div contains specific classes

Comment: All you are doing is `$('.someClass').hasClass('someClass')` ...why would you ever need that? Of course it has that class...it's in the original selector

Comment: Thats true thanks, edited